# ZyBooks Lab 2.31 decimals Java

Tags: java

I cannot figure out how to get the correct answer when averaging numbers and trying to "float it"(?) I am trying to get the answer to be 6.750, but only keep getting 6.000.

Instructions:

2.31 LAB: Simple statistics
Part 1
Given 4 integers, output their product and their average, using integer arithmetic.

Ex: If the input is:

8 10 5 4
the output is:

1600 6
Note: Integer division discards the fraction. Hence the average of 8 10 5 4 is output as 6, not 6.75.

Note: The test cases include four very large input values whose product results in overflow. You do not need to do anything special, but just observe that the output does not represent the correct product (in fact, four positive numbers yield a negative output; wow).

Submit the above for grading. Your program will fail the last test cases (which is expected), until you complete part 2 below.

Part 2
Also output the product and average, using floating-point arithmetic.

Output each floating-point value with three digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
System.out.printf("%.3f", yourValue);

Ex: If the input is 8 10 5 4, the output is:

1600 6

1600.000 6.750

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num1;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      int num4;
      int numAvg;
      int numProd;

      num1 = scnr.nextInt();
      num2 = scnr.nextInt();
      num3 = scnr.nextInt();
      num4 = scnr.nextInt();
     
      numAvg = ((num1 + num2 + num3 + num4) / 4);
      numProd = num1 * num2 * num3 * num4;
     
      System.out.println(numProd + " " + numAvg);
     
      System.out.printf("%.3f", ((double) numProd));
      System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.printf("%.3f", ((double) numAvg));
     
   }
}


`
```

Comment: You are operating with integer values. How do you expect `numAvg` to contain decimal values if it's of type int?

Comment: I messed around with changing numAvg to a double with initializing it, I messed with num1 to try and make it a double. Idk what I am doing, I just started coding

Comment: `numAvg` needs to be double. And you need to cast the division to double because all the values you are using are integers: `double numAvg = ((double)(num1 + num2 + num3 + num4)) / 4;`

Comment: But now the output of numAvg that needs to have no decimals has decimals

Comment: So what whas the original problem? If you don't operate with doubles (i.e. `numAvg` is of type `int` and you don't do any casts to `double`), you will only get integer values, which seems to be what you want, but not what you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

This lab requires you to write 2 different calculations for each part, one for integer numbers and one for double numbers. Using large input for part 1 will cause an overflow before you print the result because you defined the *product* and *average* as integers.

```
//Part 1
  int product = num1*num2*num3*num4;
  int average = (num1+num2+num3+num4)/4;
  System.out.println(product+" "+average);
//Part 2
  double prod = ((double)num1)*num2*num3*num4;
  double ave =  (double)(num1+num2+num3+num4)/4;
  System.out.printf("%.3f", prod);
  System.out.print(" ");
  System.out.printf("%.3f", ave);
  System.out.println();
```